# Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'saveContext'

Tags: ios, swift

am using firebase for integrate google signin in swift 3.0. but is shows error : Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'saveContext'

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can only use `saveContext` on a `NSManagedObjectContext`

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JimmyJames, 
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   [app saveContext];

I think you don't need NSManagedObjectContext to save.

Comment: SWIFT => let del : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        del.saveContext()

Comment: @Naveen, Make sure your AppDelegate.swift file have method name saveContext.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have `saveContext` method in your `AppDelegate` class
2. Downcast shared application to `AppDelegate`:

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the boilerplate method that comes along with AppDelegate?

```swift
// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

It's called like this:

```swift
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
```